# Automatically generate nested table of contents based on heading tags using python

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, nested-lists

I'm trying to create a nested table of content based on heading tags of HTML.

My HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>
            My report Name
  </h1>
  <h1 id="2">First Chapter                          </h1>
  <h2 id="3"> First Sub-chapter of the first chapter</h2>
  <ul>
    <h1 id="text1">Useless h1</h1>
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
  </ul>
  <h2 id="4">Second Sub-chapter of the first chapter </h2>
  <ul>
    <h1 id="text2">Useless h1</h1>
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
  </ul>
  <h1 id="5">Second Chapter                          </h1>
  <h2 id="6">First Sub-chapter of the Second chapter </h2>
  <ul>
    <h1 id="text6">Useless h1</h1>
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
  </ul>
  <h2 id="7">Second Sub-chapter of the Second chapter </h2>
  <ul>
    <h1 id="text6">Useless h1</h1>
    <p>
      some text
    </p>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

My python code:

```
import from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import codecs
#Access to the local URL(Html file)
f = codecs.open("C:\\x\\test.html", 'r')
page = f.read()
f.close()
#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page,"html.parser")
tree = html.fromstring(page)#extract report name
ref = page_soup.find("h1",{"id": False}).text.strip()
print("the name of the report is : " + ref + " \n")

chapters = page_soup.findAll('h1', attrs={'id': re.compile("^[0-9]*$")})
print("We have " + str(len(chapters)) + " chapter(s)")
for index, chapter in enumerate(chapters):
    print(str(index+1) +"-" + str(chapter.text.strip()) + "\n")

sub_chapters = page_soup.findAll('h2', attrs={'id': re.compile("^[0-9]*$")})
print("We have " + str(len(sub_chapters)) + " sub_chapter(s)")
for index, sub_chapter in enumerate(sub_chapters):
    print(str(index+1) +"-" +str(sub_chapter.text.strip()) + "\n")
```

With this code, I am able to get all the chapters and all the sub-chapters but it is not my goal.

My goal is to get the below as my table of contents:

```
1-First Chapter
    1-First sub-chapter of the first chapter
    2-Second sub-chapter of the first chapter
2-Second Chapter    
    1-First sub-chapter of the Second chapter
    2-Second sub-chapter of the Second chapter
```

Any recommendation or ideas on how to achieve my desired table of contents format?

Comment: Are you trying to create the ToC as a nested HTML list, as plain text, or as something else? I read your question as wanting to automatically generate a HTML ToC with links,

Comment: @bob0the0mighty, for the moment I need it as a plain text and I will insert it into pdf later...

Comment: Can you modify your HTML some? Generally, you should only have one H1 tag per page and if you format your HTML semantically you would simplify searching for specific elements

Comment: @bob0the0mighty  No, I cannot modify my HTML cause It's Auto-generated File.

Comment: boo, cause that markup is jacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` after finding all the data associated with each chapter:

```
from itertools import groupby, count
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
data = [[i.name, re.sub('\s+$', '', i.text)] for i in soup(content, 'html.parser').find_all(re.compile('h1|h2'), {'id':re.compile('^\d+$')})]
grouped, _count = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in groupby(data, key=lambda x:x[0] == 'h1')], count(1)
new_grouped = [[grouped[i][-1][0][-1], [c for _, c in grouped[i+1][-1]]] for i in range(0, len(grouped), 2)]
final_string = '\n'.join(f'{next(_count)}-{a}\n'+'\n'.join(f'\t{i}-{c}' for i, c in enumerate(b, 1)) for a, b in new_grouped)
print(final_string)
```

Output:

```
1-First Chapter
    1- First Sub-chapter of the first chapter
    2-Second Sub-chapter of the first chapter
2-Second Chapter
    1-First Sub-chapter of the Second chapter
    2-Second Sub-chapter of the Second chapter
```

Answer (score 1):

If your willing to changer your HTML layout to something similar to below:

```
<html>

<head>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <h1>
      My report Name
    </h1>
    <section>
      <h2 id="chapter-one">First Chapter</h2>
      <section>
        <h3 id="one-one"> First Sub-chapter of the first chapter</h3>
        <ul>
          <h4 id="text1">Useless h4</h4>
          <p>
            some text
          </p>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h3 id="one-two">Second Sub-chapter of the first chapter</h3>
        <ul>
          <h4 id="text2">Useless h4</h4>
          <p>
            some text
          </p>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2 id="chapter-two">Second Chapter </h2>
      <section>
        <h3 id="two-one">First Sub-chapter of the Second chapter</h3>
        <ul>
          <h4 id="text6">Useless h4</h4>
          <p>
            some text
          </p>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h3 id="two-two">Second Sub-chapter of the Second chapter</h3>
        <ul>
          <h4 id="text6">Useless h4</h4>
          <p>
            some text
          </p>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </section>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Then your Python code becomes a bit simpler:

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import codecs

#Access to the local URL(Html file)
with codecs.open("index.html", 'r') as f:
  page = f.read()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page,"html.parser")
tree = html.fromstring(page)#extract report name
ref = page_soup.find("h1").text.strip()
print("the name of the report is : " + ref + " \n")

chapters = page_soup.findAll('h2')
for index, chapter in enumerate(chapters):
    print(str(index+1) +"-" + str(chapter.text.strip()))
    sub_chapters = chapter.find_parent().find_all("h3")
    for index2, sub_chapter in enumerate(sub_chapters):
       print("\t" + str(index2+1) +"-" +str(sub_chapter.text.strip()))
```

I updated the page reading code a little and tried to use more idiomatic python in the updated script.

Also, note that:

```
sub_chapters = chapter.find_parent().find_all("h3")
```

find_all is relative to the parent of the chapter and not the entire document